# Having battery cells in parallel does increase autonomy ? (My load is a constant power load. DC/DC)

Tags: battery-operated, batteries, nimh, alkaline

I have 4 AA alkaline cells and I'm trying to figure out which is the **best cell configuration to achieve maximum autonomy with constant power load.**

I understand that if your load is a constant current device the best approach is the parallel configuration. If you can work in the low voltage region (1.5V down to 0.8V for alkaline) the capacity of all the cells stacks and you get more autonomy.

Scheenshot (Energizer E91 AA alkaline datasheet - single cell) :

[image]

But if my load is a DC/DC (boost for this case), Having a series or parallel configuration does increase my autonomy in some way ? **I'm thinking that when the cells voltage is decreasing the DC/DC demands more current; then the overall autonomy is the same as in series configuration**.

Example :

[image]

I know that Alkanine cells capacity is also dependable of how much current you demand but my **question is more related to the parallel-series configuration with any kind of cells** (Alkaline, NiMH, ...) using a DC/DC as load.

*Edits : Typo*

Comment: Your DC/DC will have losses which will be worse at low input volts especialy when the current increases with a constant power load .

Comment: Correct. I know that the DCDC will have a % efficiency, and is dependable of input voltage and the output current requested to the DC/DC (datasheets charts, etc). But my question is more about the batteries arrangement. If I can get more autonomy having cells in parallel than in series. Lets assume that the DCDC is "perfect" and has no losses.

Comment: "All other things being equal", and if you have a DC/DC that will accept either a parallel or series arrangement of the same number of cells (e.g. 2 cells), then the series arrangement of cells results in less power loss (I^2.R losses in conductors), because the current is half, therefore power lost in conductors is a quarter.  But this should be traded off against the %-efficiency of the DC/DC at those two input-V ranges, to work out which is better (least losses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paralleling them will increase the capacity arithmetically, so if you put two 2,000 mAh batteries in parallel you get 4,000 mAh.

Putting cells in parallel increases the battery ampere-hour rating, putting them in series increases the available electromotive force.

You need to make sure that your battery will supply the voltage required for the time you want, beyond that you might as well just parallel them up if you can. Just try to use identical models from the same batch, because if one string is at a higher voltage than the other it will try to charge it up.